# Embed Qt on android

Tags: android, qt

I build a voice calculator dektop app using Qt. Now when i try to embedd the same code for android apk it gives an error that sapi.h cannot be embedded that is used for voice. What must be the required steps that should be taken to cross platform the same desktop application on android?

Comment: SAPI is used only for Windows in QtSpeech so if it is included somewhere in your code you can exclude it for Android. Post the code and error message for more details

Comment: But if i would exclude sapi then how would i enable text to voice function in android